# How to trigger AJAX confirmbutton server-side and if "Yes" then run server-side code

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am new to ASP.NET and cannot figure out how to do the following.  I am saving a record in server-side code.  If the record is new (adding vs. editing), then I want to ask a user a question where they will respond with a Yes or No.  If Yes then I want to have server-side code executed.

I think I would use the AJAX confirmbutton but I don't know how to call it from server-side code and how to have server-side code execute if the user chooses Yes.

Comment: show your buttons markup please...

Comment: I haven't added anything yet because I am unsure of what to do or what to add.

Answer (score 0):

Give something like this a shot:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?');" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

Comment: how would I simulate the user clicking the button from the server-side code?  Can I hide the button from showing on the ASP.NET page?  I don't want the user to see the button.  I just want to ask the user a question.

Comment: @user54064: How is the user adding the record? Where are they adding it from? A grid, etc.?

Comment: The user clicks a Save button.  Then I run serve-side code to save the record.  After a successful save then if the record is new then I want to ask the user a question.

Comment: Is it just a basic form where they enter information and hit save? Are any of the fields a unique identifer that you can use to check whether the record exists, like a PO # for example?

Comment: I don't understand what you are getting at.  On the client side I have a Save button that the user clicks once they enter all the data into textboxes.  Then the save button fires server-side code that saves the record.  If the record is a new record then I want the user to get a message box that ask then a question that they respond with Yes or No.  If Yes, then I want server-side code to execute.  If No, then I want to do nothing.

Comment: Say for example you had a PO # field that was unique for each PO, you could use a TextChanged event w/ AutoPostBack to query the DB and see if the PO exists, and then add logic to determine whether a confirmation should be shown. One alternative is to use an XmlHttpRequest OnClientClick of the button to check the DB and show the confirmation if it is a new record.